# Newtonsoft Serializing object to a custom output

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, elasticsearch, json.net, nest-api

I know this is silly question, can anyone help me out on this ...?

Required below output in C#, am using "www.newtonsoft.com" json generator dll.

Required output using JsonConvert.SerializeObject :

```
{
  "must": [
    {
      "match": {
        "pname": "TEXT_MATCH"
      }
     },

     {
        "_bool": {
        "rname": "TEXT_BOOL"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My C# class design is as below :

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Must[] must { get; set; }
}

public class Must
{

    public Match match { get; set; }
    public Bool _bool { get; set; }
}

public class Match
{
    public string pname { get; set; }
}

public class Bool
{
    public string rname { get; set; }
}
```

Output I am getting after JsonConvert.SerializeObject is as below :

```
{
  "must": [
    {
      "match": {
        "pname": "TEXT_MATCH"
      },
      "_bool": {
        "rname": "TEXT_BOOL"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do elaborate with more description. What problem are you facing?

Comment: am using this json doc as an query to elasticsearch tool which accepts json document as an input to itself. Here if you see the required output of "Must" class is container of "match & bool", both classes are surrounded by an extra curly bracket ("{") around its internal classes. Which i am not able to get using JsonConvert.SerializeObject. 

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Yeah..I have noticed it. Unfortunately, I don't think so. The additional curly braces are removed from the Newtonsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the required output there are 2 objects in the array. In the one you get there is one object with both Match and Bool properties. The following way of creating the object and serializing should give what you're looking for:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Rootobject root = new Rootobject();
    root.must = new Must[2];
    root.must[0] = new Must() { match = new Match() { pname = "TEXT_MATCH" } };
    root.must[1] = new Must() { _bool = new Bool() { rname = "TEXT_BOOL" } };
    string result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, 
        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "must": [
    {
      "match": {
        "pname": "TEXT_MATCH"
      }
    },
    {
      "_bool": {
        "rname": "TEXT_BOOL"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```